# Extract number in a String java

Tags: java, string, split

I have a quite simple question here is that i have a string 0-1000
say `str = "0-1000"`

I successfully extract 0 and 1000 by using `str.split("-")`

Now, I am assigned to check the number because i am noticed that those two numbers can be a negative.

If I continue `str.split("-")`, then I will skip the negative sign as well.

Could anyone suggest methods for me?

Comment: please post an example of string containing negative number

Comment: Coudl you give an example of how a String containing negative numbers would look?
Would this be 0--1000?

Comment: @JohannisK I have edited with an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `String.split()` uses regular expressions to split, you could do something like this:

```
String[] nos = "-1000--1".split("(?<=\\d)-";
```

This means you split at minus characters that follow a digit, i.e. must be an operator.

Note that the positive look-behind `(?<=\d)` needs to be used since you only want to match the minus character. `String.split()` removes all matching separators and thus something like `\d-` would remove digits as well.

To parse the numbers you'd then iterate over the array elements and call `Integer.valueOf(element)` or `Integer.parseInt(element)`.

Note that this assumes the input string to be valid. Depending on what you want to achieve, you might first have to check the input for a match, e.g. by using `-?\d--?\d` to check whether the string is in format `x-y` where `x` and `y` can be positive or negative integers.

Comment: oh thanks but the one -1000 in your example is still a string.

Comment: does it know 1000 is a digit

Comment: @rickyma924 - to parse it into a `Integer` use `Integer.parseInt()`

Comment: @rickyma924 `1000` is not a digit but a string of 4 digit characters. As TheLostMind already commented you need to parse the numbers to integers in any case.

Comment: I know the part of parseInt

Answer (score 4):

You can use regex like this :Works for all cases

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "-500--578";
    String[] arr = s.split("(?<=\\d)-"); // split on "-" only if it is preceeded by a digit
    for (String str : arr)
        System.out.println(str);
}
```

O/P:

```
-500
-578
```

Comment: @JordiCastilla - You love it like you hate it? :P

Comment: is it \\d\\- enough to do what i want?

Comment: @rickyma924 no, since you don't want the digit to be part of the separator. Hence you need to use a zero-width positive look-behind, i.e. `(?<=\d)`

Comment: @TheLostMind yes... I love them because are super powerfull... but I hate them because I'm so bad with them... XD

Comment: Actually I still don't understand "(?<=\\d)\\-"

Comment: @rickyma924 - It is called *positive look behind*. It checks / matches (but does not select) whether the value to be split i.e, `-` is preceeded by the value mentioned in the brackets i.e, a digit.